C++17 static inline member variables to populate factory at static initialization time
The Context
I have a toy ECS architecture where I want to serialize and deserialize the whole app state for hot-reloading DLLs. I don't want the user to have to register all components at the beginning of the application/module init.
That means I have to infer somewhat what component types are used across my application at the beginning of the project. I could use a reflection solution, but I found another solution using C++17 inline static variables and template functions.
My Solution
I realized I could use C++17 inline static variables with inline template functions so all type usages that go through such functions end up registering unique entries in a factory map.
I declare the TypeFactory as such:
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// typeFactory.h
#pragma once

#include <map>

struct TypeFactory
{
    using TypeCtorFunc = void*(*)(void);

    inline static std::map<const char*, TypeCtorFunc> Registry;

    template<typename T>
    const inline static auto TypeInitializer = Registry.emplace(T::Name, (TypeCtorFunc)([](){ return (void*)(new T()); }));

    template<typename T>
    inline static const char* GetTypeId()
    {
        return (TypeInitializer<T>, T::Name);
    }
};

When the application gets initialized it can use the type factory right away:
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "usage.h"
#include "typeFactory.h"

using namespace std;

struct A { inline static const char* Name = "Type<A>"; int a = 0; };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << "Type Size:" << TypeFactory::Registry.size() << endl;
    cout << ((A*)TypeFactory::Registry[A::Name]())->a << endl;
    cout << ((B*)TypeFactory::Registry[B::Name]())->b << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Type IDs:" << endl;

    // Usage in same translation unit
    cout << TypeFactory::GetTypeId<A>() << endl;

    // Usage in other translation unit
    UsageOfB usage;
    cout << usage.GetTypeIdForB() << endl;

    return 0;
}

Here is a usage of another component's GetTypeId call in another translation unit:
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// usage.h
#pragma once

struct B { inline static const char* Name = "Type<B>"; int b = 1; };

class UsageOfB {
public:
    const char* GetTypeIdForB();
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// usage.cpp
#include "usage.h"
#include "typeFactory.h"


const char* UsageOfB::GetTypeIdForB()
{
    return TypeFactory::GetTypeId<B>();
}

Console output upon execution is:
Type Size:2
0
1

Type IDs:
Type<A>
Type<B>

My Doubts
I don't know the limitations this approach has...
I assume the order is unreliable and could easily change based on compiler optimization flags, etc.
I also assume that if the program is split into multiple modules (DLLs), each module will end up having its TypeFactory static member instances. If that's the case, I believe that my hot-reloading logic should have some sort of interface to query for types in each module TypeFactory.
Am I right to assume these things? And am I good to use this code under these assumptions?

This is not safe
It is very easy to make a copy&paste mistake which will cause problems later on. Consider:
struct A { inline static const char* Name = "Type<A>"; int a = 0; };
struct B { inline static const char* Name = "Type<A>"; int b = 0; };

Note how I forgot here to update the value for Name in struct B. When the latter is added to the registry, it will replace the entry for the real struct A. That means that when TypeFactory::Registry[A::Name] is called, you'll get a constructor for B back.
It's better if you make use of the run-time type information (RTTI) facilities of C++. There are two ways:

Instead of a struct having a Name member, use typeid(T).name() to get a name generated by the compiler. The drawback is that these type names are not pretty, implementation defined, and in fact there are no guarantees by the standard that the result has to be stable or unique, though in practice they are. Maybe you don't need the textual name though, in which case you can just use the result of std::type_index(typeid(T)) as the map key.
Let every class you want to register inherit from a base class. The constructor function can then return a pointer to that base class, and callers can then use std::dynamic_cast<>() to cast this safely to the derived type if necessary, or alternatively you might just be able to export all the functionality you need using virtual functions, so you never need to cast.

Consider looking up symbols in the DLLs directly
Instead of having a registry, consider exporting the constructors in the DLLs, so that you can look them up using GetProcAddress() on Windows, or dlsym() on almost any other operating system.
Other issues

Use std::unordered_map instead of std::map, the former has faster lookups and insertions.
Use std::string as the map's key; if it's const char* then it will only compare pointers, not the contents of the string itself. If you made Name constexpr it wouldn't have worked, and neither will lookups work if you don't use T::Name but write something like TypeFactory::Registry["Type<A>"].
Use '\n' instead of std::endl.

